# POSTING data to another page in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, post

I'm working on something that allows users to edit a form they've submitted and I have two questions.

1. Say I'm on page viewform.php and the page to edit the form is editform.php. Is it safe to pass the form's ID through the url and use then use GET. I'll verify the person trying to access it on editform.php is the person who created it using a session ID tied to the username , set upon logging in.
2. If 1 isn't a safe method, how can I POST that data (using a submit button I suppose) from viewform.php to editform.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, `$_GET` is safe as long as there isn't any sensitive data transferred. An ID is what is commonly used

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correct, what you are looking for is how to persist data across requests using forms? Because then you can have a submit URL specified in the action attribute in the form, and you can access the values of the form from that URL through the Request Object. And for submitting your data to the same page, you can use $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] which carries a reference to the page you are on. So, to answer your question, your viewform.php will have:

```
<form action="editform.php">
<input type="text" name="inputvariable" />
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

And in editform.php, you can access inputvariable's value by accessing $_REQUEST['inputvariable']

Hope this helps.

Comment: Could I used $_POST since the action is going to editform.php, or do I need to use $_REQUEST? I understand what $_POST is, but I've never used $_REQUEST so I'm unsure of how that differs. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Well $_REQUEST contains both POST and GET variables in it. However, you can't use $_POST to access the inputvariable, since the default submit method for forms is GET. Thus, you will be able to access the inputvariable through $_GET['inputvariable']. Alternatively, and the recommended approach is, you could specify method="post" as an attribute in the form. Then you could access $_POST['inputvariable'].

Answer (score 0):

Why not set the method of the submitting form to 'POST'. Using 'GET' could lead to someone modifying the URL of the page and inserting data that could have some undesired effects on your website.

If using POST, when receiving the data, set your variables as such

```
$var1 = $_POST['variable1'];
```

Comment: I know how to post to the same page. I was asking how I can post data to editform.php to verify the user who is submitting it.

Comment: Why not POST the id then as Paul had stated above. Simply a more secure way of sending the same information

Comment: I'm asking how I post to a different page. Do I have to type the url of it? If I simply type $var = $_POST['var1'] won't it just post to the page I'm on?

Comment: I believe I may have misinterpreted your initial question. If you're looking to pass a user ID (for arguments sake, we'll just say it's a user ID you're trying to pass), why not use a session variable. Set it to the ID on the authentication page for the user as 

   $_SESSION['user_id'] = $User_ID

Then, for as long as the session is valid, you could just get the ID, on any page as

$User_ID = $_SESSION['user_id'];

Is this more along the lines of what you were asking?

Answer (score 0):

You can save the Id in the $_SESSION array then match the id you got from the url with the id you saved in the $_SESSION.If they does not match you can show an error message.This will prevent your site from behaving undesired way if anyone changes the url.